# Change split view divider size in Mojave

Tags: mojave, split-view

Mojave has introduced [a very clear divider](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/8pmxdv/macos_mojave_split_screen_now_has_a_very_clear/) when we use two apps in full screen.

The issue is that it is very large. How can I get the divider to be as in High Sierra ?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do that?

Comment: No I did not. My strategy has been to increase the resolution of the screen and increase the font size.